# Condional Formatting

Tags: google-apps-script

I am attempting to write a app script. The section I am having problems with is the condtional formatting section. I want it to run to the col starting in A3 and compare it with the block in A2. if the number in A[i] is less than A2 then preform the formatting.

When i run it, it seems to preform the formatting randomally.

```
`function formating()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Walking');
  var columnO = sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
  var oValues = columnO.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < oValues.length; i++) {
    if (oValues[i][0] >= 'A2') {
      debugger;
      sheet.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 1).setBackgroundColor('green');
    }
  } `
```

Second question. Is there any way to have the mobile app be prompted to input numbers? It works on the browser, but the documentation is using a bunch of terms that make me think it might work. but I could be wrong. If not any suggestions on how to have someone be prompted from a phone and enter the number in the spreadsheet?

Thanks

Comment: `'A2'` returns "A2", not the value in cell A2.

Comment: Thank you. That solved many problems.